# Why the same coding got different result when playing the same .wav file?

Tags: java, multithreading, wav, audio-player

Test21.java works fine. I copied Test21.java to Test22.java by only changing all "Test21"s to "Test22"s and then executed it, I got "java.lang.NullPointerException".
Test21 is listed below:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;

public class Test21 extends Thread {
    private String name;

    class AudioTest {



    public void AudioPlay() {

            ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();

            try{
              Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
              AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(classLoader.getResourceAsStream("audio1.wav"));

                  clip.open(inputStream);
                  clip.start();
                  while (!clip.isRunning())
                      Thread.sleep(10);
                  while (clip.isRunning())
                      Thread.sleep(10);
                  clip.close();
                } catch (Exception e)
                    {
                      e.printStackTrace(); 
                      System.out.println(e); 
                    }
            System.out.println("done"); 
        } 
    }
    AudioTest au1 = new AudioTest();
    public Test21(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
             if (au1!=null) {au1.AudioPlay();}
             System.out.println(name);
        }finally{}
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Thread t1 = new Test21("First Thread");
        Thread t2 = new Test21("Second Thread");
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

Test22.java is listed below:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;

public class Test22 extends Thread {
    private String name;

    class AudioTest {

        public void AudioPlay() {

            ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();

            try{
              Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
              AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(classLoader.getResourceAsStream("audio1.wav"));

                  clip.open(inputStream);
                  clip.start();
                  while (!clip.isRunning())
                      Thread.sleep(10);
                  while (clip.isRunning())
                      Thread.sleep(10);
                  clip.close();
                } catch (Exception e)
                    {
                      e.printStackTrace(); 
                      System.out.println(e); 
                    }
            System.out.println("done"); 
        } 
    }
    AudioTest au1 = new AudioTest();
    public Test22(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
             if (au1!=null) {au1.AudioPlay();}
             System.out.println(name);
        }finally{}
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Thread t1 = new Test22("First Thread");
        Thread t2 = new Test22("Second Thread");
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

Initially Test21.java got "java.lang.NullPointerException" also, but after I made some modification of no meaning, it worked. I can't understand why.

Comment: "some modification of no meaning" and it started working? strange definition of "no meaning"! Are both files being started *from same location*? How? **Where** is the NPE being throw? Stack trace?

Comment: I did something like changing from "private String name;" to "String name" and changed it back.  NPE occurs at:  Test22$AudioTest.AudioPlay(Test22.java:15) and Test22.run(Test22.java:39)

Comment: seems like `getResourceAsStream("audio1.wav")` is not finding the file - try printing the value returned by `getResource("audio1.wav")` to see where the file is expected

Comment: I just open Test22.java and execute it. It can play audio.wav now. Either getResourceAsStream("audio1.wav") or getResource("audio1.wav") works. I still don't know why? May be after it took a rest for a long time, it got recovered-:)